# Prove, that $ (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^3\geq\frac{9n}{2}*[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2]$

Tags: inequality

Let n be a natural number, $\displaystyle n\geq2$ and the real non-negative numbers $x_1, x_2,...,x_n $ with the property that $ x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2=3n^2 $
Is this inequality true?
$\displaystyle (\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^3\geq\frac{9n}{2}*[(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i)^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2]$ 
I asked yesterday a similar question, but I have reasons to think that this is true.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider function $$f(y)= y^3-\frac{9n}2(y^2-3n^2)$$
Its derivative is $$f'(y)=3y(y-3n)$$
so,  $\forall y>0$ $$f(y)\geq f(3n)=0$$
Now take $$y=\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$

Comment: why is $f(y) \geq f(3n)? $

Comment: $y>3n \to f'>0 \to f(y)>f(3n). y<3n \to f'<0 \to f(y)>f(3n)$

Comment: I got it, thank you! In the fist case, the function is strictly increasing and in the second strictly decreasing.